# Can't query data from contentful to gatsby project

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

Don't get the query to contentful to work.
Receive error message:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'allContentfulMagArticle' of undefined`

`data`is undefined inside the Posts component. Can't see what i'm doing wrong here.

```
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import Post from "./post.js";
import './posts.css';

export const query = graphql`
    query {
    allContentfulMagArticle{
        edges{
            node{
                index
                title
                name
                subHeading
                extract {
                    raw
                    }
                slug
                }
            }
        }
    }
`
const Posts = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <section className="posts">
            <ul className="post-list">
                {data.allContentfulMagArticle.edges.map(({ node }) => (
                    <Post
                        key={node.index}
                        id={node.index}
                        node={node}
                        title={node.title}
                        name={node.name}
                        // image={node.frontmatter.featuredImage.childImageSharp.fluid}
                        subheading={node.subheading}
                        body={node.extract.raw}
                    />
                ))}
            </ul>
        </section>
    )
}
export default Posts
```

Here my gatsby-config.js:

```
require('dotenv').config({
  path: `.env`,
})

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `XX`,
    description: `XX`,
    author: `Lisa Lee`,
    url: `https://www.tortmagazine.com`
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    'gatsby-plugin-fontawesome-css',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        accessToken: process.env.GATSBY_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Well, the issue clearly comes from the Contentful plugin. Are you getting properly the environment variables? Have you tried the query in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground to check that is well constructed?

Comment: yes it works in `localhost:8000/___graphql`. @FerranBuireu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the word "component" to describe your `Posts` but the query you are using only works in a page, or in the context of createPage (so in a template file as well). If you are indeed in a component, that will be the issue. If not, then I'm not clear what is wrong, I use the same pattern (eg: `data.edges.node.map()`) and it works for me.

The only other difference I noticed is in `gatsby-config`, I define an `environment` key. I'm not sure what the behavior is if none is defined, probably defaults to `master` so you may also want to confirm you're on the right environment.

Comment: Yes, I actually just realised this was the issue (I read the error log more carefully ^_^) That this query does not work in non-page contexts and I need it for a Posts component. So I changed to useStaticQuery and it now works. @Michel